# click and submit button id with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

my aim is to submit a button id using jquery into a database im only interested in the button not its value.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subpage.php",
        data: 'b=' + p,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            //process live
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

subpage.php

```
$item = $_POST['b'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE  id = '25' AND bttnid = '$item'");
if(count($query)==0){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','25','$item') ");
}
```

it doesn't submit. please assit

Comment: You are missing a quotes in URL url: `subpage.php"` -> `url: "subpage.php"`

Comment: stackoverflows syntax highlighting suggests that there is a missing `"` before `subpage.php`

Comment: that is a typo sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not in jquery, the problem lies in the php statement.. changed

```
if(count($query)==0){/../}
```

to

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){/../} and it works.
```

Comment: If the correct answer was already posted by someone else it's usually polite to accept that one instead of posting the same one again and then accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fix quotes and Do it like,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "subpage.php",
  data: {b: p},
  cache: false,
  success: function(html)
  {
    //process live

  }
 });
```

Let jQuery handle the `urlencoding` of data object

Answer (score 0):

`count($query)` is wrong. You need to use `mysql_num_rows($query)` to get the number of rows returned.

Besides that, use `{b: p}` for `data` instead of a string so jQuery properly encodes `p` (even though it's most likely not necessary in this particular case since IDs are not supposed to contain any special characters anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Just 1 suggestion here: you definitely should take a look at jQuery API, which might give you answers you are looking for :)

For example: (example taken from .ajax() API page)

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

You have already got the template here and all you are left to do is just modify original values into those of your web app.

Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: In my opinion that's a bad way to learn, you should write it yourself from scratch understanding all the code and arguments etc and not copy paste then change a few lines.

Comment: Surely, the example is not meant for blindly copying and pasting. It's just a way that providers reader some better understanding to the subject. My POV would be - start off with some examples, read api descriptions, get a better idea of what it does, and then write code based on your own understanding.